# interpret python coverage unit testing

Tags: python, code-coverage

I am currently unit testing and was confused on the the below:

```
     Name                    Stmts   Miss Branch BrPart  Cover   Missing
     -------------------------------------------------------------------
     src/__init__.py             0      0      0      0   100%  
     src/__main__.py            33      2      8      3    88%   76-78, 50->exit, 57->exit, 70->76
```

what exactly does the 50-> exit mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`50->exit` means that line 50 could have then exited the function, but it never did. It is one of the branches missing from your execution.